# how to see if a relation is created in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have created a relation in hybris. How to see if the relation was created? Is there a field created in backoffice or in code? My code

```
        <relation code="CartEntries2B2BUnits" autocreate="true" localized="false" generate="true">
            <sourceElement qualifier="cartEntry" type="CartEntry" cardinality="many">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
            </sourceElement>
            <targetElement qualifier="b2bUnit" type="B2BUnit" cardinality="one">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
            </targetElement>
        </relation>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After build you can see changes on java code. After initialize/update you can see new relation type and new fields on source and target type in type system at backoffice.

**Sidenote**

- By an one-to-many relation you will find a new attribute on the model.
- By a many-to-many relation an own ModelType will be created. Here is a picture with an example for it. [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230779/difference-between-relations-and-collections-in-hybris/37239837#37239837)